# NuGet restores/installs/locks invalid dll variant for UWP app

Tags: uwp, nuget, visual-studio-2017, google-api-dotnet-client, .net-standard

New UWP project (targeting 10586 or AU version, doesn't matter).
When installing package `Google.Apis` 1.20 (or other versions) project.lock.json contains following lines:

```xml
{
  "version": 2,
  "targets": {
    "UAP,Version=v10.0": {
      "Google.Apis/1.20.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Google.Apis.Core": "1.20.0",
          ...          
          "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.11"
        },
        "compile": {
          "lib/win81/Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll": {},
          "lib/win81/Google.Apis.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/win81/Google.Apis.PlatformServices.dll": {},
          "lib/win81/Google.Apis.dll": {}
        }
      },
```

I am wondering why the compile/runtime nodes are referencing lib/win81 while the [package itself](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Google.Apis/1.20.0) contains `netstandard1.3` folder.

If I install `Google.Apis.Core`, it references `netstandard1.3` dlls from this package and still `win81` dlls from `Google.Apis`.

Wondering, why is that and how to force it to use netstandard1.3 instead?

---

Here is a structure and nuspec of the package:

[image: Google Apis package tree]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Google.Apis</id>
    <version>1.20.0</version>
    <title>Google APIs Client Library</title>
    <authors>Google Inc.</authors>
    <owners>google-apis-packages</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet</projectUrl>
    <description>The Google APIs Client Library is a runtime client for working with Google services.
          The library supports service requests, media upload and download, etc.

          Supported Platforms:

          - .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6

          - NetStandard1.3

          - Windows 8 Apps

          - Windows Phone 8 and 8.1

          - Portable Class Libraries</description>
    <tags>Google</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group>
        <dependency id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.20.0" />
        <dependency id="Zlib.Portable.Signed" version="1.11.0" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
        <dependency id="log4net" version="2.0.3" />
        <dependency id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.20.0" />
        <dependency id="Zlib.Portable.Signed" version="1.11.0" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.3">
        <dependency id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.20.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Collections" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.IO" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Net.Http" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.Threading" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.0.11" />
        <dependency id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.1.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the [Google APIs Client Library 1.20.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/) Nuget package, it supported follow platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6
- NetStandard1.3
- Windows 8 Apps
- Windows Phone 8 and 8.1
- Portable Class Libraries

Same as [Google APIs Core Client Library 1.20.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Core/) library. So we are not sure if all the features of this package support UWP platform, but it should be worked for UWP. I'm not sure why you need to change the Dll reference if this package can work for UWP app, if you are met issues when building the uwp app with this package, please try to update the .Net Core version to 5.2.2 in the `project.json` file as follows, it will build successfully and you can try to go on.

```
{
 "dependencies": {
  "Google.Apis": "1.20.0",
  "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2"
}
```

Anyway, reference which dll depend on how the [google-apis-packages](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/google-apis-packages) team  package the library, we cannot directly change it. The `compile` just shows the directory structure.  If you want to force change it, you may need to package the library by yourself, details please reference [Creating a Package](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package). In my opinion packaging by yourself may be fussy and this package possible cannot be used in uwp.

Comment: Wu, thank you for your answer. My question was not about specific package but in general why NuGet chose to use win81 lib instead on netstandard13 lib.

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov, It depend on  how the publisher package the library. Please reference Creating a Package I already mentioned above.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the answer I am looking for. I have exact library and exact target project. Which line in .nuspec triggers NuGet or VS to use win81 library over netstandard13?

Comment: @AlexSorokoletov reference [Matching assembly versions and the target framework in a project](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks#matching-assembly-versions-and-the-target-framework-in-a-project).  Maybe you go to dead end as I said it determined by the nuget package owner.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google .Net clinet](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) library does not currently support UWP. We are hoping to support UWP in v2 release which should be early 2017 see [#787](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/787)